# Função que copia vetor para outro, já passando o endereço de destino como parâmetro

Tags: c

Quero fazer uma função que copia um vetor de double para outro vetor, alocando o novo vetor na própria função que faz a cópia.

Eis a função:

```
void copiarvet(double *vet_origem, double *vet_destino, int n)
{

    vet_destino = malloc(n*sizeof(double));

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        vet_destino[i]=vet_origem[i];
}
```

Dessa forma, não funciona de forma alguma.
Eu fiz de outra forma, fazendo a função retornar um ponteiro pra double, ao invés de void, e dessa forma deu certo.

Gostaria de entender, por que, ao tentar fazer dessa maneira, já passando o endereço como parâmetro não está dando certo.

Comment: E porque não usa https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy?

Comment: Que erros dá ao tentar compilar?

Comment: @jorge-b. Agora compilou, era um erro de síntaxe simples. Mas a função de fato não funcionou.

Comment: @Maniero, nenhum motivo em particular. Só queri saber por que do jeito que fiz não dá certo.

Comment: @GustavoOliveira o bom programador só vai pedir ajuda quando esgotou as tentativas de encontrar o erro, e não quando aparece o primeiro erro e em vez de tentar perceber vai perguntar.

Comment: Boa tarde, @JorgeB. Agradeço a dica, mas o erro de sintaxe não foi o que me levou a fazer a pergunta. Mas sim, o fato da função não funcionar corretamente ao passar o ponteiro por parâmetro.